# Make the UItextField text non selectable while still being able to interact with the textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c

[Need to prevent this type of UI Interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDERH.png)I have a textfield on whose selection I show a UIPicker. The item selected from the UIPicker is shown in the textField after the Picker resigns first responder. But if I long press the UITextField, it gives me the option to select the textField text.

Any workarounds or solutions would be highly appreciated.

```
 UITextField *CatpickerField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:self.categoryView.bounds];
CatpickerField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[[CatpickerField valueForKey:@"textInputTraits"] setValue:[UIColor clearColor] forKey:@"insertionPointColor"];


CatpickerField .textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
CatpickerField.text= @"Category";
UIPickerView * pickerCAt = [UIPickerView new];
pickerCAt.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
pickerCAt.tag=1001;
pickerCAt.delegate = self;
pickerCAt.dataSource = self;
pickerCAt.showsSelectionIndicator = NO;

UIToolbar *toolBarcat= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
[toolBar1 setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonCancelcat=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  target:self action:@selector(barButtonCancelAction:)];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonDonecat=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  target:self action:@selector(barButtonAction:)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexiblecat = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
toolBarcat.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:buttonCancelcat,flexiblecat,buttonDonecat,nil];

CatpickerField.inputView = pickerCAt;
CatpickerField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar1;

self.CatPickerviewField = CatpickerField;
[self.categoryView addSubview:self.CatPickerviewField];
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDERH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add LongPressGestureRecognizer to UITextField.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr 
   = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(enableTextField)];
lpgr.delegate = self;
lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
[self.textField addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

and handle it:

```
 -(void)enableTextField
  {
     textField.enabled = YES;
  }
```